# Toggle function weirdness with IE8

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, toggle, show-hide

I have looked at many other similar threads, but my question is more basic. Since I am new to javascript/jQuery and learned to code with Chrome as my browser, I have not had much need for supporting dumb browsers. But, some colleagues of mine are stuck with IE8 due to work restrictions.

That being said, I have a site that show/hides divs using a button that triggers several toggle instances as follows:

```
$('#button1').on('click',function() {
    $('.body').toggle();
    $('.sidebar').toggle();
    $('.legend').toggle();
});

$('#button2').on('click',function() {
    $('.body').toggle();
    $('.sidebar').toggle();
    $('.legend').toggle();
 });
```

The default state for my divs are defined by inline style elements as follows:

```
<div class='body' style="display: show">...</div>
<div class='sidebar' style="display: none">...</div>
<div class='legend' style="display: show">...</div>
```

When I try to toggle my divs in chrome, everything works fine. When I try this in IE8, clicking button #1 hides the `.body` and `.legend`, but `.sidebar` div is not toggled to show.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a `display  : inline-block;` on sidebar ?

Comment: The `display:none` style is inline within each div, but, to answer your question - yes, all the divs are in a wrapper that has a css `display: block` styling.

Comment: Display:show isn't a thing.

Comment: Better to say, `show` is not an *valid* value for the display attribute, see reference MDN for [`CSS display:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

Comment: Oh, okay. I guess it is an unnecessary style, since by default, those are shown. That still doesn't tell me why the `.sidebar` div with inline `display:none`, does not reveal when the toggle is initiated in IE8?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to show what you are doing ! It's getting confusing to know what you have done and replicate the problem on it.

Comment: Sure, here is basically my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/p2ktM/. It works just fine for me in Chrome, but not so in IE8. In fact, I can't seem to run jsfiddle in my IE8 browser!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I tested IE8 and IE7, works on both. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>My Test Page</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#Dswitch').on('click',function() {
        $('.body').toggle();
        $('.sidebar').toggle();
        $('.legend').toggle();
    });

    $('#Aswitch').on('click',function() {
        $('.body').toggle();
        $('.sidebar').toggle();
        $('.legend').toggle();

           });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
      font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    }
    #wrapper {
      width: 60%;
      display: block;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="body">
        Some body stuff to show at page load <br>
        <input type='button' value='Click to switch sidebar' id='Dswitch'>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar" style='display:none'>
        Some sidebar stuff to show on button click
        <br>
        <input type="button" value='Click to swtich back to body' id="Aswitch">
    </div>
    <div class="legend">
        Some legend stuff to show at page load
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks that did work in IE8, as you said. I'm not sure why having the code specifically wrapped in the `$(document).ready` function made the difference? I guess Chrome and modern browsers are just smarter in executing javascript.

Comment: You should always have it wrapped around document ready - meaning it executes when DOM is ready.

Answer (score 0):

```
{display: show}
```

should probably be

```
{display: block}
```

IE8 may not handle your creative CSS as well as others.